# Dropdown list not displaying in IE

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have drop down list with 5 items.

I want to send the selected item to next jsp page.

JavaScript code:

```
var display= document.getElementById('displayId');
var j;
var count =0;
for(j=0;j< display.options.length;j++){
   if(display.options[j].selected){
       displaySelected =  display.options[j].value;
      count++;
   }
}
alert(displaySelected);
```

HTML code:

```html
<SELECT NAME="displayId" id="displayId" style="width:300px;">
    <option>Host</option>
    <option>Host And Response Time</option>
    <option>Host And User Count</option>
    <option>User Count And Reponse Time</option>
    <option>Host,UserCount And Response Time</option>
</SELECT>
```

This works in Fire fox but not in IE...Can anyone find the mistake?

Comment: Apart from the concrete problem, why don't you just put it in a `<form action="next.jsp">` and get the value in `next.jsp` by `${param.displayId}`?

Comment: Maybe Ok for example project, but this is evil, follow @BalusC suggestion

Comment: To improve your chances to get better help, please Accept answers that solved your other questions. You have 6 questions already with pending answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the option `text` as you don't have any value:

```
displaySelected =  display.options[j].text;
```

Some browsers probably set the value to be the text when it's empty, IE is not among them.

Answer (score 1):

Give values to your option tags .

Like
 `<option value="Host">Host</option>`
rather than `<option>Host</option>` .

And no need to find the selected value using a loop , you can always use

```
 document.getElementById('displayId').value
```